# How to dynamically allocate an instance of a class in a global char array in C++?

Tags: c++, memory-management, pool

I have this code:

```
const int size = 1024;
char pool[size];
int nextFree = 0;

class A
{
    ...
}
```

I have to extend the functionalities of `class A` in such a way that when a client call a dynamical allocation of this class:

```
A* a = new A();
```

then the instance to be placed in the global array `pool`.

I am thinking of overloading `operator new` and inside using `placement new`. Something like this:

```
class A
{
    ...
    void* operator new(size_t size)
    {
        void * pInt = ::new (&pool[nextFree]) A();
        nextFree += size;
        return pInt;
    }
    ...
}
```

and it works until it comes to freeing the dynamic allocation where the compiler throws an error: "free(): invalid pointer". I tried overloading `operator delete` too but with no success.

Any ideas how it should be done the right way?

Comment: Your code doesn't handle alignment.

Comment: Some [useful info](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#placement-new)

Comment: @harper, it throws this error when I try using `delete` the object.

Comment: This seems like a job for `allocator_traits` and friends, specialization seems to be comfortable living there

Comment: Alignment/delete issues aside... why `nextFree++`?  I'd expect something more along the lines of `nextFree += size`.

Comment: @Killzone Kid, thanks for this info, but how should I overload `operator delete` with this?

Comment: @G.M. you are correct - I will edit that.

Comment: when you build an object with a placement new your aren't suppose tu delete it just to call the destructor as `T::~T()`

Comment: @Tyker, it is by the client requirements to use `delete` operator after `new` operator was called.

Comment: @winsett yes but placement new doesn't allocate memory it just calls the constructor  on already allocated memory so delete doesn't make sens in this case

Comment: @Tyker, thanks! Now I understand! Now by using overloading of `operator delete` where I just substract `nextFree` it works with no errors. If you wish, you could give this as an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

placement new doesn't allocate memory it just calls the constructor on already allocated memory so delete doesn't make sens. you are just suppose to call the destructor using `T::~T()` when the object is getting destroyed and deallocate memory(if needed) later.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood, you want to place your object in a pool but for the end user it should look as if they are placing object on the heap. In this case you can simply do this:

```
#include <iostream>

const int size = 1024;
char pool[size];
int nextFree = 0;

class A
{
public:
    int i = 123; // some data

    A() { std::cout << "constructor\n"; }
    ~A() { std::cout << "destructor\n"; }

    static void* operator new(std::size_t size) noexcept
    {
        void *ptr = &pool[nextFree];
        nextFree += size;
        return ptr;
    }

    static void operator delete(void* ptr, std::size_t size) noexcept
    {
        //memset(ptr, 0, size); for example
    }
};

int main()
{
    A* a = new A();
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << (a == reinterpret_cast<A*>(&pool[0])) << std::endl;
    delete a;
}
```

https://ideone.com/zMW86t

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I made it with the `placement new operator` in the overloaded `operator new` already but I like your implementation too. I have some questions though why the overload of `new` and `delete` are `static` and why `noexcept`?